# Logging format interpolation with multiple arguments

Tags: python, logging, pylint, string-interpolation

`pylint` produces the following warning:

> logging-format-interpolation (W1202):
>
> Use % formatting in logging functions and pass the % parameters as
> arguments Used when a logging statement has a call form of
> “logging.(format_string.format(format_args...))”. Such calls should
> use % formatting instead, but leave interpolation to the logging
> function by passing the parameters as arguments.

So the correct way of logging would be: `logger.error('oops caused by %s', exc)`

But how to pass multiple arguments? To have something like:
`logger.error('oops caused by %s %s')` (where to put `exc_one`, `exc_two`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass it as an ordinary positional arguments

`logger.error('oops caused by %s %s', exc_one, exc_two)`

See function [signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.error):
`logging.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)`